# what is the format I should use for the ISO timestamp in my case

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have a ISO 8061 format timestamp string "**2018-06-13T12:11:13+05:00**", what is the correct way to create `Date` object out from the String?

I tried:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let myDate = formatter.date(from: "2018-06-13T12:11:13+05:00")
```

But it doesn't work correctly, `myDate` is one hour behind. What is the format string I should use for this kind of timestamp?

Comment: @Leem just use plain `ISO8601DateFormatter` instead of `DateFormatter`

Comment: `myDate` is not one hour behind. It is the correct value. There is nothing wrong with your code. Please see http://www.maddysoft.com/articles/dates.html

Answer (score 2):

For  **ISO 8601 time zone format**

use **ZZZZZ** in capital

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
```

**EDIT**

Check the following example

I have just changed **+05:30** from  **05:00**

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")

let myDate = formatter.date(from: "2018-06-13T12:11:13+05:30")

formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
print(formatter.string(from: myDate!))
```

Output

> 2018-06-13 12:11

Comment: According to this https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime You can use but i am not sure

Comment: but zzzz is recommended to use

Comment: I tried ZZZZZ, it doesn't work, still one hour behind.

Comment: I get confused by your answer, in your code, you are first using dateFormat yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ, then changed to use yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm. Then, you print out the result....but which one I should use?

Comment: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm is the target format  You can ignore it, First time your string is converted to `myDate` and with second format i just converted it back to string to just show you

Comment: But could you please just print out `myDate` to see whether the hour is correct without the second time parsing back? Because I tried with ZZZZZ but the date is incorrect in hour field.

Comment: That's why I added target format to show you time zone role in that

Comment: OK, I don't know why, I set my iPhone timezone to GMT+5, and with your code the final date is always one hour behind the actual system time.